# Document mode in ie

Tags: virtualbox, internet-explorer-10, ie-developer-tools, browser-testing

I have a header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<html class="ie ie9" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 10]>
<html class="ie ie10" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) & !(IE 8) & !(IE 9) & !(IE 10)]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

In my virtual box I have a version of IE10 running.

```
.ie10 body {
 background:blue;
}
```

The problem is I have to stick the document into ie9 to get it to pick up the styles. Why is this not working the way I think it should.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of IE10, conditional comments are [no longer supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx).

You'll need to think of a different way to accomplish the result you're after.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance